# Adding two integer values in a singleton class

Tags: java, singleton

I have to create a method to add two integer values in a singleton class. I have the singleton set up but the public static method is where I'm messing up.

I have

```
public static newTotal() {        
}
```

but am unsure of the expression that goes inside.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

edit with code

I was specifically told to use a singleton class. I already have a bean class and need to add an integer total and then a public static method(integer x) that adds x to total

```
    public class testBeanSingleton {

    private static testBeanSingleton instance = new testBeanSingleton();

    private Integer total;

    public static testBeanSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private testBeanSingleton() {
        total = new Integer();

    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public static addToTotal() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Your method needs to return something (by which, you need to declare WHAT it's going to return ... then return it)

Comment: Also why are you declaring the method as static? Since you have this within a singleton you can always obtain the singleton instance and invoke an instance method -- effectively treating the singleton as a service object.

Comment: Yeah...using a static method defeats the whole purpose of having a singleton.  Maybe you should post your full code.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for all the comments. I was specifically told that I had to use a public static method for this singleton class. I already have a bean class and given instructions to add an Integer total and then a public static method(integer x) that adds x to the total

Comment: code I have so far

Comment: public class testBeanSingleton {

    private static testBeanSingleton instance = new testBeanSingleton();

    private Integer total;

    public static testBeanSingleton getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private testBeanSingleton() {
        total = new Integer();

    }

    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }

    public static addToTotal() {
        Integer.valueOf(total).intValue()+
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Please use enum for Singleton Pattern .This is Seriliazation safe and provides iron clad guarantee for 
singleton . You need Jdk8 for this as it uses DoubleBinaryOperator and Lambda experssion

```
public enum Operation {

        PLUS("+", (x, y) -> x + y),
        private final DoubleBinaryOperator op;
        private final String symbol;

        public double apply(double x, double y) {
            return op.applyAsDouble(x, y);
        }

        Operation(String symbol, DoubleBinaryOperator op) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
            this.op = op;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return symbol;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            final double num1 = 100;
            final double num2 = 200;
            final Operation oper = Operation.PLUS;
            double newResult=oper.apply(num1,num2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Best answer imho. Combines the usage of the `enum` to implement the singleton pattern as well as the usage of function to achieve the intended result. One minor change would be that the `apply` method could be made abstract thus having each implementor define the action in their own context.

Comment: Thanks @Aris . Yeah making it abstract is a good advice. Thinking if we can combine lambda and do that

Answer (score 0):

First, your method has to return something, an integer maybe?

Second, since you have a singleton, your method doesn't need to be static. check this:

```
public int add(int i1, int i2){
   return i1+i2; 
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
int sum = MySingleton.getInstance().add(firstNumber,secondNumber);
```

Comment: `mySingleton` should start with upper-case as it's a class name. If it's an object, then this answer is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static int newTotal() {        

}
```

Your method has to return an integer. Note the `int` after `static`.

If you want some examples, take a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: Downvoting, no need to have a static method in a singleton. As above.

Comment: That's not what the question is about

Comment: The OP asks about something in the context of a singleton object. Code posted to support the question contains something that is wrong. Answering back with something equally wrong (i.e using statics in singletons) is not the correct way to go.

Comment: Ideal answer should have explained the return type of the method as well the correct usage of the singleton pattern.

Comment: The OP is clearly a beginner and might use the term "Singleton" incorrectly and 
 possibly isn't even required to use a singleton in this context.

Comment: Unfortunately this is plain speculation. The OP has not shared their full code sample to determine what they're doing. Based solely on their description, the answer you have provided seems to be wrong to my eyes. 

Furthermore, why wouldn't a singleton be useful or not required? For example if the OP is creating a number processing service, having this a singleton is the best way to go.

Comment: If you don't know how to properly create a simple method, then it's not speculation that OP does not know what they are doing. Directly using scary words like "service object" isn't going to help OP in any way I think ;)